# Change in Stack Overflow RSS feeds?

Tags: support, rss

I've been following Stack Overflow with my RSS reader, an older version of NetNewsWire, for years, using subscriptions like "http://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag?tagnames=android&sort=featured". Quite suddenly, as of 9/27/2017, I have stopped getting new articles.

I have been unable to find, with casual research, any indication that the feeds have changed or stopped, so I'm asking here. Did something change in the way that Stack Overflow does RSS around that time?

Comment: Not sure but have you tried updating the link to use `https` instead since SO now runs on https?

Comment: That's a thought.  Will try.

Comment: Will doesn't try, Will does.

Comment: [The tag wiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/rss/info) seems to indicate to use a different format.

Comment: Seems the tag feed has stopped working